# select one more table according to the condition and add it in conditions

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.username,
       a.email,
       a.created,
       b.user_id,
       SUM(b.price) + 
       SUM(IF(d.beginner =0, 15, 0)) + CASE WHEN SUM(b.price) >499 THEN 100
                                            ELSE 0 END AS points,
       SUM(b.price) AS pris,
       b.created,
       c.user_id,
       c.referrer_id,
       c.created,
       d.id,
       d.beginner,
       d.winner_id
FROM users a,
     accounts b,
     referrals c,
     product d
WHERE a.created BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-06-30'
  AND d.created BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
  AND b.created BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
  AND a.id = b.user_id
  AND a.id = c.user_id
  AND d.winner_id = a.id
GROUP BY c.referrer_id
ORDER BY `points` DESC LIMIT 0 , 3
```

In this query I have four tables. With `product` table I want it also to be selected according to `created`. But when I do like what I did in the query its not giving me the correct result. I want to select product table also with this query where condition is that I need only to selects records from 1st of June to 30 June and put them according to the condition that it will add 15points if winner found in product table.

If you see this `SUM( IF( d.beginner =0, 15, 0 ) )` condition it works if I don't add `AND d.created
    BETWEEN  '2013-06-01'
    AND  '2013-06-30'` and if users not found in product table but having points like for example 30points  from rest of two conditions, it is not showing with this query. I don't know why?
I want both products and accounts table to be selected from 1st of june to 30th June and table users from 1st of April to 30th June

```
    SELECT a.id, a.username, a.email, a.created, b.user_id, SUM( b.price ) + 
CASE WHEN SUM( b.price ) >499
THEN 100 
ELSE 0 
END AS gr, SUM( b.price ) AS pris, b.created, c.user_id, c.referrer_id, c.created
FROM users a, accounts b, referrals c
WHERE a.created
BETWEEN  '2013-04-01'
AND  '2013-06-30'
AND b.created
BETWEEN  '2013-06-01'
AND  '2013-06-30'
AND a.id = b.user_id
AND a.id = c.user_id
GROUP BY c.referrer_id
ORDER BY  `gr` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

I have removed products table condition now from this. So its easy now to understand. I want to add table `products` where select rows only from 1st Jun to 30Jun And second condition is add 15points if users found in product table in `winner_id` column.

Comment: can you do 2 different queries and join both resultsets using the UNION clause?

Comment: I can't do it in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Your comments suggest no record is found on the product table in that range. If you still want a row brought back in such a situation then use a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Something like as follows:-

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.username,
       a.email,
       a.created,
       b.user_id,
       SUM(b.price) + 
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.beginner IS NULL THEN 0 WHEN d.beginner = 0 THEN 15 ELSE 0 END) + CASE WHEN SUM(b.price) >499 THEN 100
                                            ELSE 0 END AS points,
       SUM(b.price) AS pris,
       b.created,
       c.user_id,
       c.referrer_id,
       c.created,
       d.id,
       d.beginner,
       d.winner_id
FROM users a
INNER JOIN accounts b ON a.id = b.user_id
INNER JOIN referrals c ON a.id = c.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN product d ON d.winner_id = a.id AND d.created BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
WHERE a.created BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-06-30'
  AND b.created BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
GROUP BY c.referrer_id
ORDER BY `points` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

Comment: It was an example. I think you need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN. I am struggling to understand exactly what you require from the code. Could you add some example data?

Comment: In the above query which I mentioned I have not added product table. And all conditions in the query are running like it should. Now I have one more table 'product'. I want to add product table with condition that If user id exit in table 'winner_id' and product is registered between 1st of june to 30june then add 15points to referrer id which is from referral table.

Comment: Try the amended version, although I am still unsure of what you want to do with the sum when there is no matching record, or if there can be multiple product records in that time period for a single winner_id